# Restrict user from viewing Google app script files of google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I add restrictions to view the Google app script file for those who have access to that google sheet?

Comment: Create an Addon

Comment: Don't share as editor...

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to give access to only a few users, you can keep their Google accounts in an array in your server side code. (*.gs)

```
var users = ["abc@gmail.com","bcd@gmail.com", "cde@gmail.com"]
```

Then you deploy your code by choosing **Execute the app as user accessing the web app**

Then you verify if the user is in your list or not, by a function like:

```
function userHasAccess() {
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
  if (users.includes(user)) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```